# C++ How should functions and templates be declared together

Tags: c++, templates

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

T foo(T x,T y);
int main(void)
{
    
}

template <typename T>
T func(T x,T y) {return x + y;}
```

error:

```
        3 | T foo(T x,T y);
      | ^
main.c:3:7: error: unknown type name ‘T’
    3 | T foo(T x,T y);
      |       ^
main.c:3:11: error: unknown type name ‘T’
    3 | T foo(T x,T y);
      |           ^
main.c:9:10: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘<’ token
    9 | template <typename T>
      |          ^
```

I thought I should declare the template, so I tried to declare the template before declaring the function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

template <typename T>
T foo(T x,T y);
int main(void)
{
    
}


T func(T x,T y) {return x + y;}
```

But this is still wrong, so wondering how should I declare the template

Comment: `foo` and `func` are separate functions and both need to have the template types specified

Comment: If you are separating declaration from definition, both must have `template<...>` specifier.

Comment: "this is still wrong" as evidenced by what?

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  This will be covered in the chapter(s) on templates.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to do. From the text it seems that you want a function and a separate function template. If that is the case, what do you expect `T` to be in the non-template function? Please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

`foo()` and `func()` are not the same function.  And in the 1st example, `foo()` is not a template, and in the 2nd example, `func()` is not a template, so that is why the compiler doesn't know what `T` is in them.

Like any other function, if you are going to separate a template function's declaration from its definition (which is doable, though do be aware of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/)), they need to match either other in name and signature, including the `template<>`, eg:

```
template <typename T>
T foo(T x,T y);

int main()
{
    // use foo() as needed...    
}

template <typename T>
T foo(T x,T y) {return x + y;}
```

Though, if you move `foo()`'s definition above `main()`, you can declare and define it in one operation:

```
template <typename T>
T foo(T x,T y) {return x + y;}

int main()
{
    // use foo() as needed...
}
```